# Почему не работает javascript в веб-расширении Google Chrome?

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование

При запуске расширения в консоле ошибок появляется уведомление:

***Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' 'wasm-unsafe-eval' 'inline-speculation-rules' http://localhost:* [http://127.0.0.1:*"](http://127.0.0.1:*%22). Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-NmBln2I7QbY1BQ4Fruau1h9exJQqjpzLL3e2+zzyB+g='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.***

Я прочитал, что это как-то связано с политикой безопасности, и поэтому обращался в коде js через addeventlistener:

```
const seedgen = document.getElementById("seedgen");
const seeds = document.getElementById("seeds");
    
  
seedgen.addEventListener("click", getWord);

function seedgeneration(){

var seedphrases= [
    'belt sadness world bitter pond marriage share enact elder trial lake jungle',
    'allow track parent feel narrow drift engage all media fog voice frown',
    'stuff army upper crucial puppy found cradle riot off knife myself grant',
    'trumpet sight sound donor crash copper flower grant inspire snake future ethics',
    'near taxi disorder host cattle oppose gain remember blood wide false unhappy',
    'flee glass wall garlic soft task angle hockey champion aisle unfair media',
    'hub pupil grass rally exit shuffle poet disease cat travel palace amazing',
    'brisk celery empower minute moon whale refuse theme undo inherit click nest',
    'midnight opera advance move sign priority trophy brand mom project infant drop',
    'diary garlic brisk system repair february reflect leader table often galaxy position',
];

var seedvariate = Math.floor(Math.random() * seedphrases.length);

seeds.textContent = seedphrases[seedvariate];

}
```

Код HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylegenerate.css"/>
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
     <img src="Background.svg" class="set">
     <div class="generate">
        <img src="alert.svg">
        <div class="mnemonic">
            <button class="bt" id="seedgen">Generate new wallet</button>
            <span id="seeds"></span>
            <script src="generate.js"></script>
        </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

В чем причина?

Пробовал обращаться через addeventlistener, но ошибка та же в консоле веб-расшрений

Comment: Возможные решения вашей проблемы: [ссылка](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-desktop/issues/801) и [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46256983/script-causes-refused-to-execute-inline-script-either-the-unsafe-inline-keyw) И еще куча ссылок в интернете, просто вставив вашу ошибку в поисковую строку. Не ужели кроме политики безопасности вы ничего не нашли?